# Check row-wise if element exists in comma-separated column with position

Tags: r

Given this `data.frame`:

```
#    x     y
# 1  a b,c,d
# 2  c b,c,d
# 3  c b,c,d
# 4  a e,f,g
# 5  a b,c,d
# 6  c a,b,c
# 7  b b,c,d
# 8  c  <NA>
# 9  c e,f,g
# 10 a  <NA>
```

My desired output is:

```
#    x     y pos contains
# 1  a b,c,d  NA    FALSE
# 2  c b,c,d   2     TRUE
# 3  c b,c,d   2     TRUE
# 4  a e,f,g  NA    FALSE
# 5  a b,c,d  NA    FALSE
# 6  c a,b,c   3     TRUE
# 7  b b,c,d   1     TRUE
# 8  c  <NA>  NA       NA
# 9  c e,f,g  NA    FALSE
# 10 a  <NA>  NA       NA
```

That is, check (*by row*) if `df$x` is in `df$y` and give its position. I started down the `strsplit(df$y, ",")` path but things got complicated quickly and I know there's a simple solution.

---

Code to reproduce:

```
set.seed(5)
seq_letters <- c("a,b,c", "b,c,d", "e,f,g", NA)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(letters[1:3], 10, TRUE),
                 y = sample(seq_letters, 10, TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possibility using `match()` with `mapply()` to find the first column, after splitting the `y` column into pieces.  Then we can build the second column based on that.

```
df$pos <- mapply(match, df$x, strsplit(df$y, ",", fixed = TRUE), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
df$contains <- replace(!is.na(df$pos), is.na(df$y), NA)
```

which gives

```
   x     y pos contains
1  a b,c,d  NA    FALSE
2  c b,c,d   2     TRUE
3  c b,c,d   2     TRUE
4  a e,f,g  NA    FALSE
5  a b,c,d  NA    FALSE
6  c a,b,c   3     TRUE
7  b b,c,d   1     TRUE
8  c  <NA>  NA       NA
9  c e,f,g  NA    FALSE
10 a  <NA>  NA       NA
```

Comment: Nice example of using `mapply` and `match` together.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with reshaping

```
df_x_y =
  df %>%
  distinct %>%
  filter(y %>% is.na %>% `!` )   

df_y = 
  df_x_y %>%
  select(y) %>%
  distinct %>%
  mutate(y_split = y %>% stri_split_fixed(",") ) %>%
  unnest(y_split) %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  mutate(pos = 1:n())

matches = 
  df_x_y %>%
  left_join(df_y) %>%
  filter(x == y_split)

df %>%
  left_join(matches)
```